# Add Hyperlink to Alert with Titanium

Tags: mobile, titanium

Is it possible to add a hyperlink to an alert box when using Titanium? If so, how?

Comment: First of all plz explain in detail that you could go with custom alert by using view if yes we could do this for sure Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are asking for android then use [androidView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AlertDialog-property-androidView) property of alertDialog. You can use any view like label or webview for hyperlink in android and assign it to alert dialog's view.

**For IOS you need custom View which would look like alert dialog**